# Solve $y''-xy=0$ about the ordinary point $x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is my work so far, please tell me if there are any mistakes:

I assumed the solution is of the form $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$

Then i found the second derivative of the series, substituted the series into $y^{''}-xy=0$, and after combining the series i got $0=2c_{2} +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k[c_{k+2} (k+2)(k+1)-c_{k-1}]$

I figured out that $c_2=0$ , and $c_{k-1}=c_{k+2} (k+2)(k+1)$ . Then i started substituting values of $k$ starting with $1$:

$k=1$, $c_0=c_3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$

Since $c_0=2c_2=0$, $c_3=0$

$k=2$,  $c_2=c_3 \cdot4 \cdot3$

I am not sure how to go further with this problem.

Comment: See [Airy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

Answer (score 1):

You mean $y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$.

$c_0$ and $c_1$ are determined from the initial conditions at $0$, which you didn't specify.  For $k = 1$ you should have $c_3 = c_0/6$.

Your $k=2$ is wrong: it should be $c_1 = c_4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$.
Again, $c_4 = c_1/12$ where the initial conditions determine $c_1$.

$k=3$ gives you $c_5$ in terms of $c_2$, but $c_2 = 0$ so $c_5 = 0$.

$k=4$ gives you $c_6$ in terms of $c_3$, which you know (in terms of $c_0$) from $k=1$.

etc,

Answer (score 1):

It's better to express the recursive formula as:

$$c_{k+2}=\frac{c_{k-1}}{(k+2)(k+1)}.$$

You'll notice that $c_0$ and $c_1$ will be your constants. Recall that the recursive formula holds for $k=1,2,...$.